# Editing photoshop smart layers in fireworks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks, smartobject

If I import a psd file with smart layers into Fireworks, is it possible to edit one of those smart layers the same way you would be able to in Photoshop?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, when you double-click the layer it doesn't open up a new window with the isolated layer as it does in Ps.

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question? Fireworks lacks the code structure to edit Smart Objects.

Comment: There are a lots of things in Photoshop that Fireworks can also do, but require different user actions to complete

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you even need to do this. Do your editing in Photoshop then go to Fireworks. K.I.S.S.

Comment: Not everyone has Photoshop installed. If you receive a file created in Photoshop and you only have Fireworks, this solution doesn't really work.